# Oracle database v$parameter.resource_manager_plan / V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER.resource_manager_plan field

Tags: database, oracle

Is there anyway v$parameter.resource_manager_plan / V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER.resource_manager_plan can change on its own. Other than someone explicitly changing this value can some other oracle program have a side effect that would result in this value changing.

value is switching between null and DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN and I am trying to figure out what is going on if DBA is not changing it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can define windows that specify which resource manager plan is active at any given time. See [Windows and Resource Plans](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/schedover.htm#ADMIN13102) for some documentation on the subject.